# Can I apply for an NSF grant to create a new course, and how to create a budget for it?

Tags: funding, tenure-track, nsf, hbcu

I just started a tenure-track assistant professor position at a historically black university (School of Architecture). I would like to create a new course from scratch, the course is offered at many similar schools but not in my school. To be able to teach this course, I need to obtain some equipment/hardware that is valued at $15000.

Can I apply for an NSF grant for the purpose of creating this course? I saw some grants that are dedicated to improving STEM education in HBCU, will my course fit within these grants considering that my course is related to building science? And what other budget items (besides equipment) I have to consider, i.e. my salary, a TA salary,.....? I'm currently finishing my PhD and never applied for a grant before, so any input would be much appreciated!

Comment: https://www.nsf.gov/funding/index.jsp

Comment: You should reach out to your PhD advisor, department, and office of research. Surely one of them has experience with NSF grants for this type of thing. You'll have to find the relevant NSF program, which isn't always trivial. You'll probably also want help with writing it, since it is a big endeavor in itself!

Comment: If you think this question is on topic please mark the question up. Some people just marked off topic, this brings down my reputation which will ultimately lead to banning me from posting further questions.

Comment: Another possible funding source is the US Department of Education.  Something like this could easily be part of a grant funded by the HBCU program at ED, but such grants are typically much larger (hundreds of thousands of dollars per year) Chances are that the institution is regularly submitting those larger proposals to ED, and you could probably get a project like this included in such a proposal.

Comment: In general, NSF EHR would typically not fund something like this- rather they want to fund research in STEM education that produces fundamental knowledge about teaching and learning and that has a broader impact on teaching practice at other institutions.

Comment: I'm re-opening, as (1) the question was edited with clarifying comments, and (2) I really fail to see why this was closed in the first place. As currently phrased, it's asking for advice about grants, not for a specific grant.